# OptionParser throwing 'Missing Argument' for no reasons

Tags: ruby, exception, optparse

I only have 1 possible option and it is parsed as following:

```rb
  def parse_options
    options = {}
    options[:markdown] = false
    OptionParser.new do |opts|
      opts.on('-md', '--markdown', 'Use Markdown Syntax') do
        options[:markdown] = true
      end
    end.parse!
  end
```

As you can see the option doesn't require any argument. What I find even stranger is this works:

```
command -md
```

but this throws the exception:

```
command --markdown

in `parse_options': missing argument: --markdown (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
```

Any ideas? I read the doc and multiple examples but can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you paste your entire code for the class so that we can test it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a two letter switch like that. With

```
opts.on('-m', '--markdown', 'Use Markdown Syntax') do
```

it works fine. See **Short style switch** under [OptionParser documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html#method-i-make_switch)